# Link Embedded resource items in imagelist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

I have to add an image in ImageList to a button from the resource file with path. I have tried below code:

```
private void AddMyImage()
{
//assign image to imagelist
imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"Resources\SoccerBall.jpg"));
//Assign the ImageList to the button control.   
button1.ImageList = imgList;
// Select the image from the ImageList (using the ImageIndex property).    
button1.ImageIndex = 0;
imgList.ImageSize = new Size(120, 120);
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
AddMyImage();
}
```

I get an ExceptionUnhandled error on runtime saying System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '...\Resources\SoccerBall.jpg'

What will be the resource path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var imageStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApp1.Resources.SoccerBall.jpg");

if(imageStream != null)
{
   var image = Image.FromStream(imageStream);

    imgList.Images.Add(image); 
}
```

Where WindowsFormsApp1 should be the namespace of your application. NOTE: make sure your image is set to Embedded Resource as the build action in Visual Studio (click on the image in solution explorer and for the properties set Build Action to Embedded Resource).